# Minimal CommonJS implementation

Tags: javascript, desktop, commonjs

I'd like to use some `CommonJS` compliant modules in some of my scripts. Those scripts are just meant to do things on my laptop: it's not in the browser, it's not really in the server either. I just manipulate a `mongodb` that I use locally.

So I wonder, what is the best way to do that? I only found outdated wrappers that would provide CommonJS capabilities **and** the mongo shell.

Should I handcode a `require` system? Should I handcode a workaround? Is there already a minimal loader existing?

All your ideas regarding the matter will be appreciated, for sure.

Pointers towards implementation of other parts of CommonJS would be appreciated too.

Comment: Is there a reason that node.js wouldn't work here?

Comment: Well node.js does work here but I'd rather use the mongo shell and another way to include commonJS modules

Comment: Ah - your question didn't really mention using mongo shell as a requirement.

Comment: well mongo shell is just an extended SpiderMonkey so a good general answer should fit

Comment: There is a [list on the commonjs website](http://www.commonjs.org/impl/).  Several of these wrap SpiderMonkey.

Comment: Well I already checked that page and nothing seemed to just provide CommonJS compliance. Some are DBs, some are frameworks, lots are outdated or 404...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

@Mog

You should try out http://code.google.com/p/gpsee/
which is having general-purpose C API for embedding SpiderMonkey & CommonJS.